# Mysql Between Date

Tags: php, mysql

I have table material :

- id : int
- title : text
- date_operation : date

And i have this data :

```
    1, title1, 2016-06-02
    2, title2, 2016-06-02
    3, title3, 2016-06-03
    4, title4, 2016-06-03
    5, title6, 2016-06-03
    6, title7, 2016-06-05
    7, title8, 2016-06-05
    8, title9, 2016-06-06
    9, title10, 2016-06-06
    10, title11, 2016-06-06
    11, title11, 2016-06-07
    12, title12, 2016-06-08
```

I would to dipaly all material where date_operation between 2016-06-02 AND 2016-06-06 :

**I try with this :**

```
SELECT * FROM `material` WHERE date_operation = '2016-06-02' AND '2016-06-06'
```

**But show me this result :**

```
1, title1, 2016-06-02
2, title2, 2016-06-02
3, title3, 2016-06-03
4, title4, 2016-06-03
5, title6, 2016-06-03
6, title7, 2016-06-05
7, title8, 2016-06-05
```

**I would like to see this result :**

```
1, title1, 2016-06-02
2, title2, 2016-06-02
3, title3, 2016-06-03
4, title4, 2016-06-03
5, title6, 2016-06-03
6, title7, 2016-06-05
7, title8, 2016-06-05
8, title9, 2016-06-06
9, title10, 2016-06-06
10, title11, 2016-06-06
```

Answer (score 5):

**Try this**

```
SELECT *
FROM `material`
WHERE (date_operation BETWEEN '2016-06-02' AND '2016-06-06')
```

Comment: (1) What exactly do the parentheses do?  (2) How is the second value interpreted?  I don't see this as solving the OP's problem, so additional explanation is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a time component on the "date" value.  `BETWEEN` is dangerous with dates.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT *
FROM `material`
WHERE date_operation >= '2016-06-02' AND date_operation < '2016-06-07';
```

This will work regardless of whether the value has a time component or not.

You could also use the `date()` function (with `between` even), but that can impede the use of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM `material` WHERE date_operation BETWEEN '2016-06-02 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-06 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

**TryThis**

```
SELECT * FROM `material` WHERE date_operation >= '2016-06-02' AND date_operation <='2016-06-06'
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use ternary operators to perform MYSQL query fast . Try this :-

```
`SELECT * FROM material WHERE date_operation >= '2016-06-02' AND date_operation <= '2016-06-06'`;
```